# Nothing displayed in *ngFor angular

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

i have this json file :

```
{
        "id": 1276,
        "etabName": "YAssineDev",
        "etabType": "OUR_SCHOOL",
       "users": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "username": "YassineDev",
                "firstName": "yassine",
                "lastName": "messaoud",
                "active": true,
                "payant": false,
                "creatdateTime": "2021-06-08",
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "roleName": "ADMIN_USER",
                        "description": "admin user"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

i want to display the username of the users tab in the html,
i have tried with *ngFor:

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let t of tabs.users">
            <td>{{ t.username }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**getMethod**

```
  dataEtabUser() {
    this.cr.getdataEtab().subscribe(data=> {
      this.tabs = data
    })
  }
```

**ngOnInit**

```
this.dataEtabUser()
```

but nothing displayed

Comment: Make sure you receive the data by printing it to console `console.log(data);` ...  what is the type `this.tabs` include the type in your question please ... or add [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to know more about what you have

Comment: type of the data:any =[] , and all my data are displayed in the consol

Comment: You can't iterate over an array of users that is, in turn contained in an array of tabs, if that is what you're doing. You would need to either flatten out your users into a users array with a foreach loop over tabs, for example. Or is tabs accidentally pluralized?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataEtabUser() works correctly

```html
<div *ngFor="let t of tabs">
  <tbody *ngFor="let user of t.users">
    <tr *ngFor="let data of user">
      <td>{{ data.username }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</div>
```